# aws iot rule query statement "union"

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

How to use the query statement in IoT rule query to insert two dynamodb items (i.e. rows) to the table like UNION in general SQL.

```
SELECT 
CAST(clientid() as String) AS PartitionKey, 
CONCAT('CRT#EngineOverheat#', CAST(ts as String)) AS SortKey, 
temp AS Temperature
FROM 'device/eng_temp'
UNION
SELECT 
CAST(clientid() as String) AS PartitionKey, 
CONCAT('HIST#EngineOverheat#', CAST(ts as String)) AS SortKey, 
temp AS Temperature
FROM 'device/eng_temp'
```

Comment: Hi @Cat, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Writing a nicely formatted question will increase your chances to get an answer. For example, you could split your code over several lines, and prefix each of those lines with 4 spaces, this will display them with a "code" font.

Comment: @Cat What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Is it to write two items to a dynamodb table from a single MQTT message?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is **not possible** to build JOINs / UNIONs between two queries in AWS IoT SQL.

> Refer to this AWS discussion topic @ https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=224413
>
> Additionally, on Stackoverflow @ [Query multiple Topics at once using IoT Rule SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737902/query-multiple-topics-at-once-using-iot-rule-sql)

Hope that helps!